# How to import from maven public repo to Talend data integration for tJava to use?

Tags: java, maven, talend

I am new to Talend so this may be a basic question.  I am trying to create a Talend job to manage Flyway DB migrations.  Since Talend does not connect to Flyway directly, I wanted to simply add the dependency to the project's POM and add the code to my project.  Although I've read a bunch of articles, I can't figure out how to do a Maven build in Talend which pulls down components from the repo to my job.

Based on what I read, this is a 4 step process:

1. Update the default POM.xml in Talend.
2. Build the Talend project to pull down the jars.
3. Use tLibraryLoad component(s) to add the import statement
4. Use tJava (or maybe tJavaFlex) to write the actual Flyway code.

I think I understand steps 1, 3 and 4, but can't seem to figure out step #2.

I have added this to the POM in Talend

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

[image]

But when I build my code (right click on the project name and select build) the Flyway jars (with any dependencies) are still not in the Talend modules (i.e. the list of jar files Talend has).

[image]

If I was coding straight up Java, I can just added that XML snippet and do a maven build.  Done.  Clearly, I don't understand part of this and hopefully someone can help me understand.  Thanks.

My expected results would be to add the maven dependency to the POM and have the jar be available in the Talend modules list so I can import it with the tLibraryLoad component.  But what is happen is nothing at all.  When I do a Maven build the jar files are not getting downloaded or even showing as available in the Talend module list.

Comment: By the way, if there's a better way to do this, I am not locked into those 4 steps.  I just don't understand how to use Talend to run Java code containing external libraries and need to be able to do that.  thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to use maven project settings, I think they are poorly documented.
What you could do is simply use `tLibraryLoad` to load your jars, by browsing and selecting them from your local filesystem; then use any `tJava` component to write your code.

```
tLibraryLoad (load jar) -- OnSubjobOK -- tJava (import statement and code that uses jar)
```

When you build your job, it will bundle the jars you added to the classpath of your job.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a really bothering issue but prior to version 7.x you have to download manually the required jars and include it using tLibraryLoad in a job or (which one I prefer) add it as routine dependency be then make this routine a dependency of your jobs (plural). Now, they finally added the long awaited feature of using maven. This is not yet exactly what we want (ie the possibility to add it directly to pom file for project wide use), actually they propose to use maven uri in routine dependency. But at least there is that.

Comment: I am using 7+, but I guess you're confirming that we still really can't do a Maven build the same we you would if it was just a Java project without Talend.  At least that tells me I'm doing the same thing other people are.